# Is there a way to control Yorda in your first playthrough?

Tags: ico

My girlfriend and I just really enjoyed playing through Brothers: A Tale of Two Sons together and I figured she'd probably enjoy ICO too.

We have the PS3 HD remake of the original but I haven't started it yet, I was wondering if there is anyway that she can control Yorda (maybe a cheat code... or something similar) that won't require a solo playthrough? I've noticed you can download saves from certain sites, but they seem to be profile restricted.

I managed to download a save and get it onto the PS3. It gave me a warning that any trophies wouldn't apply, which was promising, but when starting a new game, and releasing Yorda, I didn't get the option to switch to two players.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you save file in the game has a funny hieroglyphic symbol next to its logged time (you can view this in the continue game load-up screen), you must go into the games settings and enable 2 players once Yorda is freed from her cage.